# Загрузка и обработка картинок на Php

Tags: php, codigniter

Как правильно заливать и обрабатывать картинки? Весь день мучаюсь ничего не выходит.Вот надо избавиться от подобного.Нужно чтобы все картинки имели размер как у первой. Поставил ограничения на загрузку,минимальный размер 1000 x 750.После этого делаю `resize` до указанныx значений,но всеравно получается каша,где высота выше где ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])){
    $file = $this->upload_file('userfile', 'products_img');

    if(!empty($file['error'])){
        $data['file_error'] = $file['error'];
    }else{
        $uploadedImg = FCPATH.'uploads/products_img/'.$file['file_name'];
        $mainImg = $this->resize_img(array('path' => 'products_img', 'raw_name' => $file['raw_name'], 'ext' => $file['file_ext']), 1000, 700);
        $sliderThumb = $this->resize_img(array('path' => 'products_img', 'raw_name' => $file['raw_name'], 'ext' => $file['file_ext']), 150, 100);
        unlink($uploadedImg);
    }     
}
```

Загрузка и Resize

```
public function upload_file($file, $folder){
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH.'uploads/'.$folder;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['min_width']     = '1000';
    $config['min_height']    = '750';
    $config['encrypt_name']  = true;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload($file)){
        return $this->upload->data();
    }else{
        return array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
}

public function resize_img($params, $width = 1000, $height = 750){
    $config['image_library']  = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']   = FCPATH.'uploads/'.$params['path'].'/'.$params['raw_name'].$params['ext'];
    $config['create_thumb']   = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']          = $width;
    $config['height']         = $height;
    $config['new_image']      = FCPATH.'uploads/'.$params['path'].'/'.$params['raw_name'].'_'.$width.'x'.$height.$params['ext'];

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

    if($this->image_lib->resize()){
        return 'uploads/'.$params['path'].'/'.$params['raw_name'].'_'.$width.'x'.$height.$params['ext'];
    }else{
        return $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` ;)

Comment: Ну понятное дело что TRUE) зачем мне получать растянутые изображения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maintain_ratio` Можно перевести как сохронять отношение сторон.
т.е:

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
```

Меняем на

```
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
```

И получаем все картинки одного размера

**Очень важно!**

Помните картинку начнет растягивать/сжимать ;).

Поэтому, если отношение сторон у картинки не совподает с оригиналом, надо **делать кроп**.

Можно писать самому, но я бы посмотрал на библиотеки.

Например:

https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

Или умный кроп

https://codegeekz.com/cropping-images-entrop/